# woocommerce view orders shortcode, view order button not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I have a custom my-account page with tabs, i want to display order details on the orders tab. I tried adding the shortcode [my_orders].

```
function shortcode_my_orders( $atts ) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'order_count' => -1
), $atts ) );

ob_start();
$customer_orders = wc_get_orders( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
    'customer' => get_current_user_id(),
    'page'     => $current_page,
    'paginate' => true,
) ) );
wc_get_template(
    'myaccount/orders.php',
    array(
        'current_page'    => absint( $current_page ),
        'customer_orders' => $customer_orders,
        'has_orders'      => 0 < $customer_orders->total,
    )
);
return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('my_orders', 'shortcode_my_orders');
```

This displays the order on the front-end but when i click on the view order button it redirects me to dashboard page. How to make the view order button work as it normally works on default my-account page.

Comment: My view orders page has the URL localhost/my_site/my-account/#view-orders. The default view button has link to URL localhost/my_site/my-account/view-order/order-number . I think this is a problem. I don't want to change the WordPress core files.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Is there a way I can display the content of orders tab of default my-account and still have the view button working.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searches, I found out that it is possible but I will have to rewrite all the woocommerce default code which would not make sense, the other option is to use rewrite rules but again that would give errors since the orders section have a lot of functionality like order again, pay for pending order etc. so it would again be a bad idea. So anyone viewing this question i would suggest that you use the default dashboard and then make any front-end changes in that.